# word "suggested" for already accepted proposal

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to say "suggested" about something that was suggested and got accepted/approved? Is it common?

For example,

> I suggested a tag synonym on this; the suggestion got a few votes and was accepted.
>   Nobody can accept or reject it now because it is already decided.

Is it still possible to say "suggested synonym"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *suggested* just means that it a suggestion was made and does not imply that the suggestion was accepted / rejected or not. In other words, regardless of whether the suggestion is accepted or rejected, or if no decision has been reached yet, it has still been suggested.

There is a slight problem with your example sentence. You seem to be missing an article:

> I suggested a tag synonym on this; **the** suggestion got a few votes and was accepted.

Comment: fixed example situation

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can say this as long as it was suggested *then*, which is what the word means.